# Javascript/PHP onclick to create table

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I have only been doing PHP for about two weeks now.

I am having some trouble figuring out how I would go about turning this php code into a table once the onclick event has occurred. I have tried multiple times but I keep breaking the code.

Any direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Also do not use `SELECT * FROM ...`, but select the specific columns you need, like `SELECT products.productCode, products.productName, orders.comments FROM ...`.

Comment: Can you add your Javascript `popUp` function code, too?